# How to use java.time.ZonedDateTime / LocalDateTime in p:calendar

Tags: jsf, primefaces, calendar, timezone, java-time

I had been using Joda Time for date-time manipulation in a Java EE application in which a string representation of date-time submitted by the associated client had been converted using the following conversion routine before submitting it to a database i.e. in the `getAsObject()` method in a JSF converter.

```
org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter formatter = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a Z").withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime("05-Jan-2016 03:04:44 PM +0530");

System.out.println(formatter.print(dateTime));
```

The local time zone given is 5 hours and 30 minutes ahead of `UTC` / `GMT`. Therefore, the conversion to `UTC` should deduct 5 hours and 30 minutes from the date-time given which happens correctly using Joda Time. It displays the following output as expected.

```
05-Jan-2016 09:34:44 AM +0000
```

► The time zone offset `+0530` in place of `+05:30` has been taken because it is dependent upon `<p:calendar>` which submits a zone offset in this format. It does not seem possible to change this behaviour of `<p:calendar>` (This question itself would not have been needed otherwise).

---

The same thing is however broken, if attempted using the Java Time API in Java 8.

```
java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter formatter = java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a Z").withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("05-Jan-2016 03:04:44 PM +0530", formatter);

System.out.println(formatter.format(dateTime));
```

It unexpectedly displays the following incorrect output.

```
05-Jan-2016 03:04:44 PM +0000
```

Obviously, the date-time converted is not according to `UTC` in which it is supposed to convert.

It requires the following changes to be adopted for it to work correctly.

```
java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter formatter = java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a z").withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("05-Jan-2016 03:04:44 PM +05:30", formatter);

System.out.println(formatter.format(dateTime));
```

Which in turn displays the following.

```
05-Jan-2016 09:34:44 AM Z
```

<sub>`Z` has been replaced with `z` and `+0530` has been replaced with `+05:30`.</sub>

Why these two APIs have a different behaviour in this regard has been ignored wholeheartedly in this question.

What middle way approach can be considered for `<p:calendar>` and Java Time in Java 8 to work consistently and coherently though `<p:calendar>` internally uses `SimpleDateFormat` along with `java.util.Date`?

---

The unsuccessful test scenario in JSF.

The converter :

```
@FacesConverter("dateTimeConverter")
public class DateTimeConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            return ZonedDateTime.parse(value, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a Z").withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC));
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | DateTimeException e) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, null, "Message"), e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return "";
        }

        if (!(value instanceof ZonedDateTime)) {
            throw new ConverterException("Message");
        }

        return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a z").withZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")).format(((ZonedDateTime) value));
        // According to a time zone of a specific user.
    }
}
```

XHTML having `<p:calendar>`.

```
<p:calendar  id="dateTime"
             timeZone="Asia/Kolkata"
             pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a Z"
             value="#{bean.dateTime}"
             showOn="button"
             required="true"
             showButtonPanel="true"
             navigator="true">
    <f:converter converterId="dateTimeConverter"/>
</p:calendar>

<p:message for="dateTime"/>

<p:commandButton value="Submit" update="display" actionListener="#{bean.action}"/><br/><br/>

<h:outputText id="display" value="#{bean.dateTime}">
    <f:converter converterId="dateTimeConverter"/>
</h:outputText>
```

<sub>The time zone is fully transparently dependent upon the user's current time zone.</sub>

The bean having nothing other than a single property.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

    private ZonedDateTime dateTime; // Getter and setter.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Bean() {}

    public void action() {
        // Do something.
    }
}
```

This will work in an unexpected way as demonstrated in the second last example / middle in the first three code snippets.

Specifically, if you enter `05-Jan-2016 12:00:00 AM +0530`, it will redisplay `05-Jan-2016 05:30:00 AM IST` because the original conversion of `05-Jan-2016 12:00:00 AM +0530` to `UTC` in the converter fails.

Conversion from a local time zone whose offset is `+05:30` to `UTC` and then conversion from `UTC` back to that time zone must obviously redisplay the same date-time as inputted through the calendar component which is the rudimentary functionality of the converter given.

---

**Update:**

The JPA converter converting to and from `java.sql.Timestamp` and `java.time.ZonedDateTime`.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

@Converter(autoApply = true)
public final class JodaDateTimeConverter implements AttributeConverter<ZonedDateTime, Timestamp> {

    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(ZonedDateTime dateTime) {
        return dateTime == null ? null : Timestamp.from(dateTime.toInstant());
    }

    @Override
    public ZonedDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp timestamp) {
        return timestamp == null ? null : ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(timestamp.toInstant(), ZoneOffset.UTC);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Your concrete problem is that you migrated from Joda's zoneless date time instance [`DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) to Java8's zoned date time instance [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) instead of Java8's zoneless date time instance [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).

Using `ZonedDateTime` (or [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html)) instead of `LocalDateTime` requires at least 2 additional changes:

1. **Do not force a time zone (offset) during date time conversion**. Instead, the time zone of the input string, if any, will be used during parsing, and the time zone stored in `ZonedDateTime` instance must be used during formatting.

   The [`DateTimeFormatter#withZone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withZone-java.time.ZoneId-) will only give confusing results with `ZonedDateTime` as it will act as fallback during parsing (it's only used when time zone is absent in input string or format pattern), and it will act as override during formatting (the time zone stored in `ZonedDateTime` is entirely ignored). This is the root cause of your observable problem. Just omitting `withZone()` while creating the formatter should fix it.

   Do note that when you have specified a converter, and don't have `timeOnly="true"`, then you don't need to specify `<p:calendar timeZone>`. Even when you do, you'd rather like to use `TimeZone.getTimeZone(zonedDateTime.getZone())` instead of hardcoding it.
2. **You need to carry the time zone (offset) along over all layers, including the database**. If your database, however, has a "date time without time zone" column type, then the time zone information gets lost during persist and you will run into trouble when serving back from database.

   It's unclear which DB you're using, but keep in mind that some DBs doesn't support a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column type as known from [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm) and [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) DBs. For example, [MySQL does not support it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294183/is-there-mysql-equivalent-to-oracles-timestamp-with-time-zone). You'd need a second column.

If those changes are not acceptable, then you need to step back to `LocalDateTime` and rely on fixed/predefined time zone throughout all layers, including the database. Usually UTC is used for this.

---

### Dealing with `ZonedDateTime` in JSF and JPA

When using `ZonedDateTime` with an appropriate `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` DB column type, use the below JSF converter to convert between `String` in the UI and `ZonedDateTime` in the model. This converter will lookup the `pattern` and `locale` attributes from the parent component. If the parent component doesn't natively support a `pattern` or `locale` attribute, simply add them as `<f:attribute name="..." value="...">`. If the `locale` attribute is absent, the (default) `<f:view locale>` will be used instead. There is **no** `timeZone` attribute for the reason as explained in #1 here above.

```
@FacesConverter(forClass=ZonedDateTime.class)
public class ZonedDateTimeConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object modelValue) {
        if (modelValue == null) {
            return "";
        }

        if (modelValue instanceof ZonedDateTime) {
            return getFormatter(context, component).format((ZonedDateTime) modelValue);
        } else {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(modelValue + " is not a valid ZonedDateTime"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) {
        if (submittedValue == null || submittedValue.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            return ZonedDateTime.parse(submittedValue, getFormatter(context, component));
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(submittedValue + " is not a valid zoned date time"), e);
        }
    }

    private DateTimeFormatter getFormatter(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) {
        return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(getPattern(component), getLocale(context, component));
    }

    private String getPattern(UIComponent component) {
        String pattern = (String) component.getAttributes().get("pattern");

        if (pattern == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("pattern attribute is required");
        }

        return pattern;
    }

    private Locale getLocale(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) {
        Object locale = component.getAttributes().get("locale");
        return (locale instanceof Locale) ? (Locale) locale
            : (locale instanceof String) ? new Locale((String) locale)
            : context.getViewRoot().getLocale();
    }

}
```

And use the below JPA converter to convert between `ZonedDateTime` in the model and `java.util.Calendar` in JDBC (the decent JDBC driver will require/use it for `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` typed column):

```
@Converter(autoApply=true)
public class ZonedDateTimeAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<ZonedDateTime, Calendar> {

    @Override
    public Calendar convertToDatabaseColumn(ZonedDateTime entityAttribute) {
        if (entityAttribute == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(entityAttribute.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
        calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(entityAttribute.getZone()));
        return calendar;
    }

    @Override
    public ZonedDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Calendar databaseColumn) {
        if (databaseColumn == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(databaseColumn.toInstant(), databaseColumn.getTimeZone().toZoneId());
    }

}
```

---

### Dealing with `LocalDateTime` in JSF and JPA

When using UTC based `LocalDateTime` with an appropriate UTC based `TIMESTAMP` (without time zone!) DB column type, use the below JSF converter to convert between `String` in the UI and `LocalDateTime` in the model. This converter will lookup the `pattern`, `timeZone` and `locale` attributes from the parent component. If the parent component doesn't natively support a `pattern`, `timeZone` and/or `locale` attribute, simply add them as `<f:attribute name="..." value="...">`. The `timeZone` attribute must represent the fallback time zone of the input string (when the `pattern` doesn't contain a time zone), and the time zone of the output string.

```
@FacesConverter(forClass=LocalDateTime.class)
public class LocalDateTimeConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object modelValue) {
        if (modelValue == null) {
            return "";
        }

        if (modelValue instanceof LocalDateTime) {
            return getFormatter(context, component).format(ZonedDateTime.of((LocalDateTime) modelValue, ZoneOffset.UTC));
        } else {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(modelValue + " is not a valid LocalDateTime"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) {
        if (submittedValue == null || submittedValue.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            return ZonedDateTime.parse(submittedValue, getFormatter(context, component)).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime();
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(submittedValue + " is not a valid local date time"), e);
        }
    }

    private DateTimeFormatter getFormatter(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(getPattern(component), getLocale(context, component));
        ZoneId zone = getZoneId(component);
        return (zone != null) ? formatter.withZone(zone) : formatter;
    }

    private String getPattern(UIComponent component) {
        String pattern = (String) component.getAttributes().get("pattern");

        if (pattern == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("pattern attribute is required");
        }

        return pattern;
    }

    private Locale getLocale(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) {
        Object locale = component.getAttributes().get("locale");
        return (locale instanceof Locale) ? (Locale) locale
            : (locale instanceof String) ? new Locale((String) locale)
            : context.getViewRoot().getLocale();
    }

    private ZoneId getZoneId(UIComponent component) {
        Object timeZone = component.getAttributes().get("timeZone");
        return (timeZone instanceof TimeZone) ? ((TimeZone) timeZone).toZoneId()
            : (timeZone instanceof String) ? ZoneId.of((String) timeZone)
            : null;
    }

}
```

And use the below JPA converter to convert between `LocalDateTime` in the model and `java.sql.Timestamp` in JDBC (the decent JDBC driver will require/use it for `TIMESTAMP` typed column):

```
@Converter(autoApply=true)
public class LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, Timestamp> {

    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime entityAttribute) {
        if (entityAttribute == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return Timestamp.valueOf(entityAttribute);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp databaseColumn) {
        if (databaseColumn == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return databaseColumn.toLocalDateTime();
    }

}
```

---

#### Applying `LocalDateTimeConverter` to your specific case with `<p:calendar>`

You need to change the below:

1. As the `<p:calendar>` doesn't lookup converters by `forClass`, you'd either need to re-register it with `<converter><converter-id>localDateTimeConverter` in `faces-config.xml`, or to alter the annotation as below

   ```
    @FacesConverter("localDateTimeConverter")
   ```
2. As the `<p:calendar>` without `timeOnly="true"` ignores the `timeZone`, and offers in the popup an option to edit it, you need to remove the `timeZone` attribute to avoid that the converter gets confused (this attribute is only required when the time zone is absent in the `pattern`).
3. You need to specify the desired display `timeZone` attribute during output (this attribute is not required when using `ZonedDateTimeConverter` as it's already stored in `ZonedDateTime`).

Here's the full working snippet:

```
<p:calendar id="dateTime"
            pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a Z"
            value="#{bean.dateTime}"
            showOn="button"
            required="true"
            showButtonPanel="true"
            navigator="true">
    <f:converter converterId="localDateTimeConverter" />
</p:calendar>

<p:message for="dateTime" autoUpdate="true" />

<p:commandButton value="Submit" update="display" action="#{bean.action}" /><br/><br/>

<h:outputText id="display" value="#{bean.dateTime}">
    <f:converter converterId="localDateTimeConverter" />
    <f:attribute name="pattern" value="dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a Z" />
    <f:attribute name="timeZone" value="Asia/Kolkata" />
</h:outputText>
```

In case you intend to create your own `<my:convertLocalDateTime>` with attributes, you'd need to add them as bean-like properties with getters/setters to the converter class and register it in `*.taglib.xml` as demonstrated in this answer: [Creating custom tag for Converter with attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406474/creating-custom-tag-for-converter-with-attributes/31412640#31412640)

```
<h:outputText id="display" value="#{bean.dateTime}">
    <my:convertLocalDateTime pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a Z" 
                             timeZone="Asia/Kolkata" />
</h:outputText>
```

Comment: It is working. Thanks. The answer deserves at least one bounty as it took considerable amount of time. I will start a bounty tomorrow.

Comment: In case, a user changes a zone offset to something other than the default one in `<p:calendar>`, for example, `-0500` (`America/New_York`), it will produce a confusing result because the converter keeps on working based on the user's selected zone. The zone changed in `<p:calendar>` will have no effect. If `07-Jan-2016 12:00:00 AM -0500` is inputted, the expected date-time to be inserted into the database will be `07-Jan-2016 05:00:00 AM ET` but `06-Jan-2016 06:30:00 PM ET` will be inserted instead based on the selected zone, `+0530`. Can the calendar and the converter be synchronized somehow?

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce it. Did you also alter the input time after changing time zone?

Comment: Date and time is not changed after changing a time zone in `<p:calendar>`. Regarding a Java SE environment, the converter essentially does - `DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a Z").withZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));` `LocalDateTime localDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("07-Jan-2016 12:00:00 AM -0500", formatter).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime();` in which case, `formatter.format(localDateTime)` returns `06-Jan-2016 06:30:00 PM ET` while it is expected to return `07-Jan-2016 05:00:00 AM ET` converting `-0500` to `-0000`.

Comment: It looks like you still have set `timeZone` on `<p:calendar>`. It should be removed as shown in working snippet.

Comment: The `timeZone` attribute is no longer available in `<p:calendar>` nor the server configuration `ServerTimezone` set to `UTC`. Both of them have been threshed permanently from the application / server.

Comment: In your Java SE example, that `withZone()` step should be skipped. Wondering where it is coming from. The `LocalDateTimeConverter` in my answer only adds it when `timeZone` attribute is specified on the component.

Comment: The problem occurred because I had modified the code in the converter introducing a twist inside. The converter was further simplified a lot using a taglib. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, glad it's OK again :)

Comment: Which language format does this constructor `new Locale(String language)` accept? Another overloaded constructor `new Locale("hi", "IN")` works but this `new Locale("hi")` silently fails to work resetting the locale to the default one. This is nevertheless no longer needed anywhere in my use-cases as I do `locale="#{facesContext.application.defaultLocale}"` in `<p:calendar>`.

Comment: You can supply `hi_IN` as `language`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that in the previous comment. `new Locale("hi_IN")` has the same effect as `new Locale("hi")` - it also silently fails to work falling back to the default locale. I am currently testing in a Java SE console application.

Comment: You're right, it's interpreted as variant not as country. Awkward stuff. Think locale is better not to be supplied as string or else you have to do split and such.

Comment: For JPA, I'm using the [ThreeTen JPA project](https://github.com/marschall/threeten-jpa).  I've asked the [JSF inclusion](https://github.com/marschall/threeten-jpa/issues/10)

Comment: @Gilberto: JSF 2.3 will come with  builtin support via `f:convertDateTime`.