# Prevent localized date time from being submitted

Tags: jsf, converters, locale

The basic converter (merely a prototype) converting to and fro between `String` and `java.time.LocalDateTime`.

```
@FacesConverter("localDateTimeConverter")
public class LocalDateTimeConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) {
        if (submittedValue == null || submittedValue.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            return ZonedDateTime.parse(submittedValue, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern, Locale.ENGLISH).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | DateTimeException e) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, null, "Message"), e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object modelValue) {
        if (modelValue == null) {
            return "";
        }

        if (!(modelValue instanceof LocalDateTime)) {
            throw new ConverterException("Message");
        }

        Locale locale = context.getViewRoot().getLocale();

        return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern, locale).withZone(ZoneId).format(ZonedDateTime.of((LocalDateTime) modelValue, ZoneOffset.UTC));
    }
}
```

The date times to be submitted to the database should be based on `Locale.ENGLISH`. Therefore, it is constant / static in `getAsObject()`.

The date times to be retrieved from the database i.e. to be presented to end-users are based on a selected locale of the user's choice. Therefore, `Locale` is dynamic in `getAsString()`.

Date time is submitted using a `<p:calendar>` which is not localized to avoid troublesome.

This will work as expected unless a `<p:calendar>` component being submitted itself or some other components on the same form being submitted fail during conversion / validation in which case, the calendar component will be pre-filled with a localized date-time which will then fail to be converted in `getAsObject()` in all subsequent attempts to submit the form unless the localized date-time in the given `<p:calendar>` is reset to the default locale manually.

The following will pass on the very first attempt to submit the form as there is no conversion / validation violation.

[image]

If there is however, a conversion error in one of the fields as follows,

[image]

then both the dates in the calendar components will be changed according to the selected locale (`hi_IN`), since there is a conversion error in one of the fields which will obviously fail to be converted in `getAsObject()` in subsequent attempts, if the form holding the components is attempted to be submitted after fixing the conversion error by providing the field a correct value.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the converter's `getAsString()` you're using the view's locale for formatting the date.

```
Locale locale = context.getViewRoot().getLocale();
```

In order to use a component-specific locale, it has to be provided as component attribute. Here's an example provided that `<locale-config><default-locale>` in `faces-config.xml` is set to `en`.

```
<p:calendar ... locale="#{facesContext.application.defaultLocale}">
```

In the converter you can extract it as below:

```
Locale locale = (Locale) component.getAttributes().get("locale");
```

The base converter example of your converter has in the meanwhile been altered to take this properly into account: [How to use java.time.ZonedDateTime / LocalDateTime in p:calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883270/how-to-use-java-time-zoneddatetime-localdatetime-in-pcalendar).