# How to handle exceptions in a FacesConverter?

Tags: validation, jsf

When the date format is not correct (for example when I manually post 13,02,2018 instead of 13.02.2018 and also other incorrect dates such as 13.02.999) the app crashes. How can I fix it? (the manual input is important, i can`t just disable it).

XHTML:

```
<rich:calendar enableManualInput="true" datePattern="dd.MM.yyyy"
    value="#{myBean.data.myDate}">
    <f:converter converterId="mydate"/>
</rich:calendar>
```

Converter:

```
@FacesConverter("mydate")
public class LocalDateConverter implements Converter {
    private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter;
    static {
        formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
        formatter.withLocale(new Locale("ru"));
    }
    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        return LocalDate.parse(value, formatter); 
    }

    @Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return "";
    } else if (value instanceof LocalDate) {
        return ((LocalDate) value).format(formatter);
    } else if (value instanceof LocalDateTime) {
        return ((LocalDateTime) value).format(formatter);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value is not java.time.LocaleDate");
    }
}
```

Comment: Crashes where? In the getAsObject? Then just prevent it from crashing. It is **your** code

Answer (score 2):

Converters should throw a `ConverterException` which can contain a `FacesMessage`. This message can be displayed on your XHTML page, near the input component that caused the exception using `<h:message for="inputComponentId"/>`.

The problem occurs in your `getAsObject` method. There you should catch the `DateTimeParseException` exception and throw a `ConverterException`:

```
try {
  return LocalDate.parse(value, formatter);
}
catch (DateTimeParseException ex) {
  throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage("Invalid date: " + value));
}
```

See also:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-custom010.htm
- [How to use java.time.ZonedDateTime / LocalDateTime in p:calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883270/how-to-use-java-time-zoneddatetime-localdatetime-in-pcalendar)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need converter at all. Simply include `label` attribute in `rich:calendar` component and let system figure out if value is correct. Example:

```
<h:outputLabel for="programStartDate" value="#{msg.programStartDate}" />
<rich:calendar id="programStartDate" value="#{program.programStartDate}"
    label="#{msg.programStartDate}" inputStyle="width: 100px;"
    datePattern="#{referenceData.defaultDatePattern}"
    timeZone="#{referenceData.timezone}"
    enableManualInput="true" popup="true" required="true" />
```

Comment: I don't know RichFaces that well, and could not find it in the documentation, but does `rich:calendar` support conversion to `LocalDateTime` that the OP seems to be using?

Comment: @Jasper de Vries there are `datePattern` and `timeZone` attributes for that purpose

Answer (score -2):

use a try catch and catch the exception so it doesn't crash but continue without allowing the exception to crash your program

```
@FacesConverter("mydate")
public class LocalDateConverter implements Converter
{
    private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter;
    static {
        formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
        formatter.withLocale(new Locale("ru"));
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value)
    {
        return LocalDate.parse(value, formatter);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value)
    {
        try
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return "";
            }
            else if (value instanceof LocalDate) {
                return ((LocalDate)value).format(formatter);
            } else if (value instanceof LocalDateTime) {
                return ((LocalDateTime)value).format(formatter);
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value is not java.time.LocaleDate");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "SOME DEFAULT DATE";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I would expect the problem to be in the getAsObject and not the getAsString since the former is called when the client in the browser enters a string as a date

Comment: It will be totally unhelpful to the end user to replace it's input with some default date. Just show an error message and allow the user to fix the input.